# Wrapper for open() and open64() and see that system calls by vi uses open64()

Tags: c, wrapper, vi

I have written wrappers for both `open()` and `open64(`). Now I run vi by preloading my wrapper library using `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable and I see that the `open64()` wrapper is used instead of the `open()`. But when I strace vi I see that the system calls made is to `open()` (of course including the other system calls). What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) utility traces [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (syscall) and *open* happens to be both a syscall and a library function.  Both the `open()` and `open64()` library functions use the `open` syscall internally to request services from the kernel.  It is my understanding that using `open()` with the `O_LARGEFILE` flag is equivalent to using `open64()` to support large files in 32-bit applications.

---

If the call to `open64()` were to call the `open()` function internally, your `open()` wrapper would not be called because you cannot interpose internal library function calls.  They are resolved before runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Are you running on a 64 bit system? If so then this is no surprise. strace traces the actuall syscalls, not which functions in a library are called. On 64 bit systems `open` and `open64` are implemented by the same syscall.