# Finding process id of a process inside a syscall wrapper

Tags: c, process, wrapper

Say I have a wrapper function for each file system related system calls e.g, open(), close(), creat() etc and inside each wrapper function I need to find out the process id of the process making the syscall. Would be gratefull for some pointers. Thanks....

Comment: How are you wrapping them?  Inside the kernel?  Rewriting the functions?  What OS are you considering?  Do you trust the application that is being monitored this way?

Comment: Or are you using something like `ptrace` to trap system calls?  In that case, you probably already have the PID.

Comment: @Jeremiah..eah my question was probably incomplete. No I am not using ptrace. I am wrapping system calls in user space and it linux and yes for now applications are within my control.:-)

Comment: In that case, @sarnold's answer is what you should use.

Comment: Are you wrapping the actual [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) or library functions (like asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5203846/203667)) that happen to have the same name (like asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5245306/203667))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [`getpid(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getpid.2.html) system call; but Jeremiah asks good questions. :)